# Microsoft Azure Powershell not recognizing subscription because user email contains an educational account and a personal account

Tags: powershell, azure, hadoop

I recently signed up for a MS Azure subscription.  I used my educational email address in order to sign up for this, however I also created a personal account through Hotmail with the same email address accidentally.  Now when I try to access Power Shell Azure, I receive an error stating that my userID does not have a valid subscription, but I am able to login to the Azure portal normally and do all other functions.  I am not sure how to solve this issue.  I did use one of my previous passwords to sign up for the personal account, and is hence 
returning the following error below.

I receive this error when trying to add credentials of the personal account:

Add-AzureAccount : AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50054: Old password is used for authentication.
Trace ID: b8587199-2e95-44c5-8652-5c71bb2a8ad8
Correlation ID: 1ddd34ac-7114-4e50-ae9e-e51f6794615d
Timestamp: 2015-02-11 22:01:14Z: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I receive this message when trying to add credentials of the educational account:

PS C:> Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
VERBOSE: Account "xxx@xxx.xxx" has been added.
VERBOSE: To view all the subscriptions, please use Get-AzureSubscription.
VERBOSE: To switch to a different subscription, please use Select-AzureSubscription.
WARNING: There is no subscription associated with account

Comment: Can you try Remove-AzureAccount and then try Add-AzureAccount again?

Comment: Thank you so much ravikanth.  This solved the issue, as I was able first remove the educational account, and then added the account again and chose the personal account using the "Add-AzureAccount" command